# Textarea auto adjust to content height jQuery

Tags: jquery, automation

The problem is that when the textarea height is higher than the window the scroll sticks to the top of the textarea when it should be focus to where the caret is.

This is my code

```
function adaptiveheight(a) {
    $(a).height(0);
    var scrollval = $(a)[0].scrollHeight;
    $(a).height(scrollval);
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ve4rL/2/)

Try to make the textarea lengthy and you'll see the problem.

As much as possible I don't want a third party plugin. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this code in the end of `adaptiveheight(a)` function

```
if (parseInt(a.style.height) > $(window).height() - 30) {
        $(document).scrollTop(parseInt(a.style.height));
    }
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ve4rL/3/

**New Js code**

```
$("#description").keyup(function (e) {
    adaptiveheight(this);
});
i=0;
j=0;
function adaptiveheight(a) {
    $(a).height(0);
    var scrollval = $(a)[0].scrollHeight;
    $(a).height(scrollval);
    if (parseInt(a.style.height) > $(window).height()) {
        if(j==0){
            max=a.selectionEnd;
        }
        j++;
        var i =a.selectionEnd;
        console.log(i);
        if(i >=max){
            $(document).scrollTop(parseInt(a.style.height));
        }else{
            $(document).scrollTop(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ve4rL/5/

Comment: it worked. but it has a side effect. When you target the caret at the top and you type, the scroll is focus at the bottom of the textarea.

Comment: hmm yes i didn't thought of that let me try more

Comment: ugh theres a lot of code that I am unfamiliar with. But it works! Thank you sir

Comment: Please don't write such a shoddy JS code. Using global variables, leaving out console.log...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply maintain current page position after resizing the textarea:

```
function adaptiveheight(a) {
    var $a = $(a), $window = $(window), scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    $a.height(0).height($a.prop('scrollHeight'));
    $window.scrollTop(scrollTop);
}
```

See https://github.com/jgonera/micro.js/blob/master/micro.autosize.js.